# Phaser Can't get a character to climb a ladder right

Tags: sprite, phaser-framework, gravity

I'm making something of a platform game, and need to get a character to rise when they press a button while in collision with a ladder like sprite. Here is the code I have to do this:

```
if (this.checkCollision(this.p1, this.ropeSpot) && Phaser.Input.Keyboard.JustDown(this.keyT)){
        inventory.splice(inventory.indexOf("rope"));
        this.ropeSpot.destroy();
        this.rope = this.physics.add.sprite(628, 420, 'ropeClimb');
        this.rope.body.immovable = true;
        this.rope.body.allowGravity = false;
        if (this.checkCollision(this.p1, this.rope) && this.keyT.isDown){
            this.p1.body.setVelocityY(-200);
        }
    }
```

The player has to be in collision with the ropeSpot sprite, which is a clear sprite showing marking where a button can be pressed for an interaction, and then press the T button to destroy the ropeSpot and then spawn the rope sprite, a tall, thin sprite.

If the player presses T, which I plan to use as a general interaction button, while in collision with the rope sprite, they should rise until they release the button or are no longer colliding with the rope sprite. This doesn't occur as intended, instead resulting as a small jump.

I then tried to alter the code into this:

```
if (this.checkCollision(this.p1, this.ropeSpot) && Phaser.Input.Keyboard.JustDown(this.keyT)){
        inventory.splice(inventory.indexOf("rope"));
        this.ropeSpot.destroy();
        this.rope = this.physics.add.sprite(628, 420, 'ropeClimb');
        this.rope.body.immovable = true;
        this.rope.body.allowGravity = false;
        if (this.checkCollision(this.p1, this.rope) && this.keyT.isDown){
            this.p1.body.allowGravity = false;
            this.p1.body.setVelocityY(-200);
        }
        else if (!this.checkCollision(this.p1, this.rope) || !(this.keyT.isDown)){
            this.p1.body.allowGravity = true;
        }
    }
```

While this did cause the character to rise when the button is pressed, it couldn't stop when the button was let go or the character moved away from the rope sprite. The character only stopped when it hit something immovable, like a platform or the top of the screen. And when the character did stop, it wouldn't fall back down again, leaving it floating but still able to move left and right.

I'm unsure of what to try next, or even what I did wrong. Can someone offer a solution?

If it helps, I'm using Phaser 3 in VSCode, employing arcade physics.

Comment: in with function/method is code from? `update`, _event-callback_, ...? What is this `checkCollision` function? Can you share more code?

Comment: Its in the update method, and the checkCollision method is the standard rectangle collision detection allgorithm:

checkCollision(a, b) {
        // simple AABB checking
        if ((a.x < b.x + b.width && 
            a.x + a.width > b.x && 
            a.y < b.y + b.height &&
            a.height + a.y > b.y) ) {
                return true;
        } 
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }

Answer (score 0):

I would simply, move the inner `if`- clause out of the outer `if`- clause, and add a check if `this.rope` exists, this should solve the issue.

> Since in the posted code the first `if` clause will be entered only once, because `this.ropeSpot` is destroyed, so it can never set the gravity on again.

```
if (this.checkCollision(this.p1, this.ropeSpot) && Phaser.Input.Keyboard.JustDown(this.keyT)){
    ...
}
//only execute if this.rope is set
if (this.rope && this.checkCollision(this.p1, this.rope) && this.keyT.isDown){
   ...
}
else if (this.rope && !this.checkCollision(this.p1, this.rope) || !(this.keyT.isDown)){
    ...
}
```

Comment: This seems to have worked for the most part, but for some reason the character isn't rising to the top of the rope. Instead, when they reach a certain point, they stop and then bounce in the air until the button is let go. What the heck?

Comment: Well the player is probably not more colliding. I would suggest that you turn on the debugging of the collision boxes to see  this (`debug: true`). here an example showing this https://phaser.io/examples/v3/view/physics/arcade/100-world-bodies

Comment: I'm yet to turn the debug mode off. I can tell it's colliding. I have been able to make the character go higher by raising the number in setVelocityY from -200 to -700, but it still has the bouncing problem.

Comment: Without seeing more code I can't really say, but, the bouncing is a sign, that the gravity is active again. Maybe the `checkCollision` function is causing the this. it is the only logical solution.